# SSH daemon not starting

Tags: linux, ssh

Hi i am not able start the sshd on redhat 6.9. Here is the logs

When i try restarting service i get following error logs.

**/var/log/messages**

```
Mar  5 06:49:31 c2t26451 init: sshd main process (19225) terminated with status 255
Mar  5 06:49:31 c2t26451 init: sshd main process ended, respawning
```

**/var/log/secure**

```
Mar  5 07:37:54 c2t26451 sshd[31840]: error: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0 failed: Address already in use.
Mar  5 07:37:54 c2t26451 sshd[31840]: fatal: Cannot bind any address.
```

Here is the service status and sshd process

```
[ ~]$ sudo service sshd status
openssh-daemon is stopped
[ ~]$ ps -ef|grep ssh
root     22036 28601  0 05:26 ?        00:00:00 sshd: testuser [priv]
testuser 22042 22036  0 05:26 ?        00:00:00 sshd: testuser@pts/0
testuser 22166 22043  0 05:29 pts/0    00:00:00 grep ssh
root     28601     1  0 Mar05 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

Though one process is already running and i am wondering if i kill it i would be locked out of server permanently. Also i am not sure if i reboot the server how the effect would.

Answer (score 4):

The reason you don't see it as a service, is that sshd is running as a regular process instead of service/daemon.
From `man sshd`:

```
 -D      When this option is specified, sshd will not detach and does not become a daemon.  This
         allows easy monitoring of sshd.
```

You can check if any other network services are using the same port by issuing `netstat` command:

```
netstat -lntup
or
netstat -lntup | grep ':22'
```

What you could do is create another sshd config file with a different name and different port number. Remember to open that port in iptables. Start the other instance with new config specified:

```
sudo sshd -D -f my_new_config
```

This will start sshd the same way, as a process. Connect via ssh on your new port number and kill the other session - make sure you're killing the right one! Also, keep the first session opened just in case.

Now start your default sshd as a service, not a daemon and enable it to start with system boot.

```
service sshd start
chkconfig --add sshd
chkconfig --level 2345 sshd on
```

Now, as per your further comments:
It seems, that something is restarting sshd when killed. Might be its own config file or sshd itself, if I understand correctly (again, referring to `man sshd`):

```
sshd
     rereads its configuration file when it receives a hangup signal, SIGHUP, by executing itself with the
     name and options it was started with, e.g. /usr/sbin/sshd
```

### Questions to OP:

Would you mind posting your sshd config file, preferably with all sensitive details "censored"?
Is it a fresh OS install or a server that you "inherited"?

### Update:

I've ran a simple test, because that `-D` option got me thinking: it should not detach and run in the background.

```
cp sshd_config test_sshd    # copied config, changed port number
/usr/sbin/sshd -D -f test_sshd
ps -ef | grep sshd
root      1842  1718  0 12:03 pts/5    00:00:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D -f test_sshd
```

If I kill this process from another session or `Ctrl-c` in the session where i ran `/usr/sbin/sshd -D -f test_sshd`, normal behaviour is this process closes and does not restart.

```
kill 1769   # or Ctrl-c
ps aux | grep 'sshd -D'
root      1848  0.0  0.0 103324   880 pts/6    S+   12:08   0:00 grep sshd -D
```

This would suggest that you have some other process, script, watchdog running that is restarting sshd as a regular process when it fails, gets killed or exits in other kind of way.
Please look into your `cron` or `anacron` entries as root user, check running processes for `screen` or `tmux`.

```
crontab -l
cat /etc/anacrontab
ps -ef | grep -e 'screen' -e 'tmux'
```

Comment: when i ran 
`netstat -lntup | grep ':22'`
i got this
` tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      28601/sshd `

Comment: This output tells you, that there already is an sshd process running, with PID 28601, that is listening on 0.0.0.0 (all interfaces/IPv4 networks configured on this system) and it is LISTENing for incoming connections on port 22. And that explains why you cannot start another ssh server/daemon (service) listening on the same TCP port number 22.
Let me know, if my proposed answer is not clear enough, so I can elaborate with more detail.

Comment: The process is not getting killed, when i killed, it is starting with new process id by itself
`[ ~]$ ps -ef|grep ssh 
root 24571 1 0 04:04 ? 00:00:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -f /etc/ssh/sshd_config_9022 
root 25957 1 0 04:20 ? 00:00:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D [ ~]$ sudo kill -9 25957                                             
[ ~]$ ps -ef|grep ssh 
root 24571 1 0 04:04 ? 00:00:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -f /etc/ssh/sshd_config_9022 
root 26589 1 0 04:31 ? 00:00:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D`